# Metodo javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo problemas para ejecutar el siguiente problema que me plantean:  tengo que generar un método que devuelva la cantidad de amigos que tiene el alumno (que es un objeto con las siguientes propiedades nombre (string), apellido (string), cohorte (number), grupoDeAmigos (array de objetos).

```js
function crearClaseAlumno() {
    class Alumno {
        constructor(nombre, apellido, cohorte, grupoDeAmigos, notasCheckpoints) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.apellido = apellido;
            this.cohorte = cohorte;
            this.grupoDeAmigos = grupoDeAmigos;
            this.notasCheckpoints = notasCheckpoints;
        };
        obtenerAmigos() {
            return this.grupoDeAmigos.length
        };
    }
}
```

Intenté con el método `obtenerAmigos()` pero no funciona.

Comment: Puedes mostrar el objeto alumno?

Comment: ahi lo agregue a la descripcion de la pregunta @Vicent

Comment: Y cual es el error ? Has creado la instancia de la clase?

Comment: ¿Porqué tienes tu clase envuelta en una función?

Answer (score 3):

El problema está en 2 cosas, la primera es que no es necesario tener tu clase dentro de una función, es suficiente con tenerla afuera ya que de esta manera puedes instanciar tu clase en diferentes partes de tu proyecto y utilizarla cuando requieras, y la segunda es posiblemente no hayas instanciado tu clase.

Con tu clase `Alumno` dentro  de tu función `crearClaseAlumno()` solo la podrías instanciar dentro de esa misma función lo cual no te permitiría hacerlo desde afuera en caso de que lo requieras.

```js
function crearClaseAlumno() {
    class Alumno {
        constructor(nombre, apellido, cohorte, grupoDeAmigos, notasCheckpoints) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.apellido = apellido;
            this.cohorte = cohorte;
            this.grupoDeAmigos = grupoDeAmigos;
            this.notasCheckpoints = notasCheckpoints;
        };
        obtenerAmigos() {
            return this.grupoDeAmigos.length
        };
    }
    
    const alumno = new Alumno("Alvaro", "Vanegas", 1, ["Los panas de Stackoverflow"], 5);
    console.log(alumno.obtenerAmigos())
}

crearClaseAlumno()
```

La forma mas correcta es teniendo tu clase por fuera y así puedes instanciarla libremente de esta manera.

```js
class Alumno {
        constructor(nombre, apellido, cohorte, grupoDeAmigos, notasCheckpoints) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.apellido = apellido;
            this.cohorte = cohorte;
            this.grupoDeAmigos = grupoDeAmigos;
            this.notasCheckpoints = notasCheckpoints;
        };
        obtenerAmigos() {
            return this.grupoDeAmigos.length
        };
    }
    
    const alumno = new Alumno("Alvaro", "Vanegas", 1, ["Los panas de Stackoverflow"], 5);
    console.log(alumno.obtenerAmigos())
```

Teniendo tu clase fuera de una función te permitirá reutilizarla donde quieras, y siempre recuerda instanciarla utilizando la palabra reservada `new` mas el nombre de tu clase: `new Alumno()`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes definir la clase fuera de la función, y no has instanciado la clase con new:

```js
class Alumno {
  
  constructor(nombre, apellido, cohorte, grupoDeAmigos, notasCheckpoints) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
      this.apellido = apellido;
      this.cohorte = cohorte;
      this.grupoDeAmigos = grupoDeAmigos;
        this.notasCheckpoints = notasCheckpoints;
    }
  
  obtenerAmigos() {
    return this.grupoDeAmigos.length;
    }
}
        
let alumno = new Alumno('p','x','y',[1,2,3,4,5,6], 7);
console.log("número de amigos -> ", alumno.obtenerAmigos());
```